# Raw TCP on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, putty, tcp, telnet, google-chrome-os

I have an Acer Chromebook 13, with an ARM processor, and am trying to connect to my friend's server via TCP. I have tried all of the promising web apps for Chrome but they either will not connect or will not send commands (I'm sorry if that's not the correct wording). He says that the raw TCP/telnet on PuTTY will work but there is no version of PuTTY for Chrome (that I have found).

Answer (score 0):

As workaround You can install Linux to Your Chromebook. Easiest way is use [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Mocha Telnet Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mocha-telnet/eampcebilkabfdlnehhfpgjfceacaabj) available in the Chrome Store? This is a terminal telnet emulator app for chrome.